# How to implement a remove function in a linked list in safe rust? (cannot assign to *node because is borrowed)

Tags: rust, linked-list

```
struct Node<T> {
  content: T,
  next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}

struct LinkedList<T> {
  first: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
  size: i64
}

impl<T: std::default::Default + std::cmp::PartialEq> LinkedList<T> {
  fn new() -> Self {
    LinkedList { first: None, size: 0 }
  }

  fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
    let mut tmp_node = Box::new(Node { content: value, next: None });
    let old_first_node = std::mem::replace(&mut self.first, None);
    tmp_node.next = old_first_node;
    self.first = Some(tmp_node);

    self.size += 1;
  }

  fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
    let mut old_first = std::mem::replace(&mut self.first, None);
    match &mut old_first {
      None => {
        return None;
      },
      Some(ptr) => {
        self.first = std::mem::take(&mut ptr.next);
        let val_to_return = std::mem::take(&mut ptr.content);
        return Some(val_to_return);
      }
    }
  }

  fn remove(&mut self, value: T) {
    let mut current_node = &mut self.first;

    while let Some(node) = current_node {
      if node.content == value {
        *current_node = node.next.take();
        break;
      }
      current_node = &mut node.next;
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  
}
```

I tried to implement this function a lot but every solution I thought of, the compiler complains about some "borrow" error, in this case, the error is "cannot assign to *current_node because is borrowed". How can i avoid this error and make the current node be the next node of the linked list?

Comment: Nit: you don't need to fully-qualify `std::default::Default` and `std::cmp::PartialEq`, both are in the prelude.

Comment: Also: it looks like you don't need `Default`, and the `PartialEq` constraint can be applied only to `remove()`.

Comment: Mandatory reference: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your code is correct, it's a limitation of the compiler that it doesn't accept it. It is accepted with the nightly [Polonius](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius) borrow checker.

The simplest solution is to replace `while let` with `is_some()` and `unwrap()`s:

```rust
fn remove(&mut self, value: T) {
    let mut current_node = &mut self.first;

    while current_node.is_some() {
        if current_node.as_mut().unwrap().content == value {
            *current_node = current_node.as_mut().unwrap().next.take();
            break;
        }
        current_node = &mut current_node.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    }
}
```